# Animated movie about evil rats ruling the world

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic, animation

There was an animated movie about evil rats ruling the world form 90s or 80s (I think it was made in Europe). There were a group of people trying to survive and avoid the rats. Both people and the rats were living in underground tunnels. The people were led by an old woman telling the stories about mythical creature "the bird" that can walk in the air. The people were finally found by the rats and only the old woman and three kids survived (one of the kids was bold and deaf). The old woman also dies and the children go for a search  trying to find the bird. As there's an old legend that the world will be reborn when the bird appears again. At the end the children reach the surface and see a bird the walks in the air (flies). Any idea what the movie can be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [*Subway to Paradise*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0124147/) (AKA *Dreaming of Paradise*, AKA *Strit og Stumme*).

> In the future, pollution has driven humans deep under ground, where
> they tell legends of the paradise above. Two kids must find the path
> to the surface, while avoiding the humanoid, militaristic rats seeking
> to steal their dreams.

Comment: @npocmaka - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)